# if not a string in a file text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a file_text in this format

```
the workers have human rights.
the women have rights.
the people have to work.
```

and I have some terms like this

```
li = "human rights,the women"
```

I need to print the lines of the file_text where there is not one of the terms in the li. To do this I tried

```
for line in file_text.splitlines():
    for i in li.split(","):
            if not i in line.casefold():
                    print(line)
```

This code gives the lines where there are the terms which have not to be, can somene tell my why here "not" does not work?

Comment: you are using `i` for two separate loops. The second time you use it you overwrite the first value. Use separate variables for your loops.

Comment: You are doing two checks if one fails you print the line

Comment: What do you mean by *not one of the terms*? Lines without any of the terms? Or lines with at least one of the terms missing?

Comment: Please post the expected output. The question is not very clear.

Comment: BryanOakley: Which two loops?  He has only two loops, and in the first he uses `line`.  I don't see `i` being overwritten here.

Comment: @Georg Schölly, Lines without any of the terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you print the line whenever *any* of the words is *not* in the line. You have to check that *not any* of the words is in the line. The easiest way to do this is using the 'any' function:

```
for line in file_text.splitlines():
    if not any(i in line.casefold() for i in li.split(",")):
        print(line)
```

If you also need to know the words that occurred in that line, you can collect those in a conditional list comprehension and then check whether that list is empty or not:

```
for line in file_text.splitlines():
    contained = [i for i in li.split(",") if i in line.casefold()]
    if contained:
        print(line, "contains", contained)
    else:
        print(line, "contains none of those words")
```

Comment: What about if I need to print beside the line also the words, like print (line, i)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the thinking behind the algorithm. Think about this:

Because of the "one by one" iteration:

First If "human right" is not in line it will be printed so lines with "the woman" will be printed.

Then lines where "the woman" in not present will be printed so "human right" lines will be printed as well.

To avoid this try some other methods like `any` or a counter to see it one or two of the elements in `li` is present.

Comment: What about if I need to print beside the line also the words, like print (line, i)